# Implicit finite difference scheme for parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms, approximation, finite-differences

Let $u=u(t,x,y):[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be sufficiently smooth and consider the parabolic PDE $$u_t+u_{xx}+u_y=0.$$

Using forward/central finite differences, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{u_{i+1,j,k}-u_{i,j,k}}{\Delta t} + \frac{u_{i,j+1,k}-2u_{i,j,k}+u_{i,j-1,k}}{(\Delta x)^2} + \frac{u_{i,j,k+1}-u_{i,j,k-1}}{2\Delta y}=0.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
u_{i+1,j,k} = \frac{\Delta t}{2\Delta y} u_{i,j,k-1} -\frac{\Delta t}{2\Delta y} u_{i,j,k+1}-\frac{\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2} u_{i,j-1,k} + \left(1+2\frac{\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2}\right) u_{i,j,k} -\frac{\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2} u_{i,j+1,k}
\end{align*}

This is an **implicit finite difference scheme**.

I've got boundary conditions on $u$ for $t\to\infty$, $x\to\pm\infty$, $y\to0$ and $y\to\infty$.

Thus, I seek $u(0,x,y)$.

To numerically solve that PDE, I need to implement a nested for loop going (backwards) through the time dimension, the $x$ dimension and finally through the $y$ dimension.

**I do not know what equation system needs solving. In one dimension, $u_t+u_{xx}=0$, it's a tridiagonal matrix but I do not know how to generalize the setting to the above PDE. Could you please guide me in what system $Ax=b$ needs solving?**

Comment: What are the limiting conditions explicitly? For this equation and unbounded domains I would not tend towards finite differences intuitively.

Comment: @maxmilgram The conditions are complicated to state without a page of notations and motivations. The PDE arises as solution to an economic model and the boundary conditions are derived from underlying economic intuition. What alternative to finite differences would you suggest? The simple heat equation (without $u_y$) is often approximated numerically using finite differences in some parts of finance.

Comment: Hi @maxmilgram, would you perhaps have any idea how I could set up the equation system $Ax=b$ that needs solving? I'm not quite sure how $A$ and $b$ should look like. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is again a spare Matrix. The vector $x$ is the "flattened" array $u_{i,j}$.

Comment: @maxmilgram could you perhaps briefly write down $A$ and $b$ for me? I really struggle with imagining how these two would look like. I'd award you the bounty instantly.

Comment: Integrating heat equation backwards in time is not a [well-posed problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem). Trying to solve it numerically without a-priori assumptions about the initial solution form or without regularization will hit numerical instabilities.

Try it yourself for 1D heat equation

Comment: @uranix I did the 1D heat equation backwarts with finite time horizon $[0,T]$. This was no problem. I get arbitrarily close to the analytical solution. Regarding the equation in the question, I can solve this equation fine with an explicit scheme. I want to implement an implicit scheme as alternative check

Comment: How large was your $T$? Numerical fluctuations grow like $\exp\left(\frac{\pi^2}{h^2}T\right)$ where $h$ is the spatial step size. For example with $h=0.01$ and $T = 0.0004$ the growth factor would be around $10^{17}$. If you're using double precision, the solution would be completely lost due to numerical errors.

Comment: @uranix I do not know where your error formula comes from. Just have a look at the ``Black-Scholes PDE''. After some substitutions, it transforms to the 1D heat equation. It's very simple and efficient to solve (even for large values of $T$). It's a very popular PDE in economics and mathematical finance, see also the Feynman-Kac theorem.

Comment: My bad, I've confused your equation with $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$.

Comment: @uranix (1) Is the change in sign of $u_{xx}$ that much of a change? (2) Do you perhaps know what equation system needs solving for the above implicit scheme for $u_t+u_{xx}+u_y=0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110433/discussion-between-uranix-and-alex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible in your situation to make the following change of variables:

$$
\tilde{t} = -t
$$

So that:

\begin{aligned}
-u_{\tilde{t}} + u_{xx} + u_y = 0\\
u(-\infty, x, y) = f(x,y)
\end{aligned}

Thus, your finite difference scheme will be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I wanted to opt for an implicit scheme because an explicit scheme does not always converge. I wanted to be sure that the approximation converges to the right solution.

Comment: Are you saying that, by a change of time, $\tilde{t}=-t$, any implicit scheme is equivalent to a corresponding explicit scheme?

Comment: I meant that you need to discretize pde again using forward/central finite differences. Or you can suppose that in your equations $\Delta t < 0$ and you will step back in time on each iteration (scheme will be explicit). But again if you need implicit scheme, that is not a solution

Comment: I already implemented an explicit scheme for the PDE. But I'd like to compare the results and implicit (or Crank-Nicolson) schemes seem to better with respect to convergence. I, however, am unsure how about what equations I need to solve during the iteration steps given the additional $u_y$ derivative.

Comment: @Alex I see the issue. As a matter of principle you can interpret your system as follows: $AX=B$, where $X_{j,k} = u^i_{j,k}$, $B_{j,k} = u^{i+1}_{j,k}$ and A is a matrix of coefficients. And then solve this directly.

Comment: Could you please provide a detailed statement of $AX=B$ in your answer? I'll accept your answer then :) I'm not quite sure how to write down $A$. So, if I have $M$ time points, $N$ points along the $x$ axis and $L$ points along the $y$ axis, I got to solve $M-1$ equation systems of size $NL$ each, one for each time point (minus one for the terminal condition as $t\to\infty$)?